# Is connecting a grounding rod to the positive side of a battery wrong?

Tags: grounding, solar-energy

[image]

I have a 12 V battery being charged by a wind generator. The installation instructions show the grounding rod on the negative side. I have been having power issues with the batteries draining to quickly. When trying to troubleshoot the issue, I have found that the grounding rod is connected to the positive terminal. Could this be causing a problem?

Comment: it takes two different earth gnd connections to cause a problem when connected to different polarities. Otherwise Never.

Comment: Measure the current into the grounding rod. If none shows up, that's probably not the issue. If some shows up, you have something to track down. It might be for the reason others mentioned (the negative terminal also has a path into ground.) But it might be something else, too. It might not have anything to do with the grounding rod, but something else entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it could absolutely be causing a problem assuming the negative side of the generator has a path to ground also, which is possible.  Your battery could be draining through the earth connection back to the grounded negative side of the generator.